# is mapping local subdomain to subfolder of another site possible?

Tags: http, redirect, webserver, subdomain

I am developing a multilingual ecommerce website at *www.my-domain.com*. My pages require two language markers - one for the website interface - and one for the product being viewed. This facilitates customers to browse foreign products while having access to menus etc in their own language. I'm using a subdomain to mark the website interface and a directory to mark the product language: *www.fr.my-domain.com/product-id/zht*.

I have a cloud file storage bucket at *www.cloud-domain.com*. I am using the cloud server to host product images for my site (250,000 JPGs @ 25GB). The images are divided into folders for each language supported: *www.cloud-domain.com/de/*; *www.cloud-domain.com/fr/*; *www.cloud-domain.com/it/*.

In the spirit of same-subdomain SEO for each language's product images, I want to **transparently** map directories as follows:

```
www.fr.my-domain.com/img/ to www.cloud-domain.com/fr/
www.de.my-domain.com/img/ to www.cloud-domain.com/de/
www.it.my-domain.com/img/ to www.cloud-domain.com/it/
```

Is this possible without access to *www.cloud-domain.com* server configuration? What is the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if you have access to www.fr.my-domain.com/img.

there is a http status code 301(Moved Permanently). You configure your apache(or nginx) at www.fr.my-domain.com, have it respond every request for www.fr.my-domain.com/img with a 301 response  directing to www.cloud-domain.com/fr/

I am not clear about the exact grammar, but you can find out by googling

Comment: This is not transparent. The goal is to serve www.fr.my-domain.com/img without the address bar changing to www.cloud-domain.com/fr/. This solution gives SEO credit to the www.cloud-domain.com/fr/ domain, not my own.